# How much electric power can we generate at home by use of treadmill like devices and dynamo?

Tags: mechanical, power-grid

I goto gym to burn about 600-1000 KCal. Instead, can we conserve this and be less dependent on grid for basic lighting and TV and other electrical energy needs at home? What are challenges today?

Comment: it's likely more realistic to directly expend energy manually instead of using electrical appliances; pumping water, washing laundry, mowing grass, riding a bike, opening the garage, sweeping instead of vacuuming, hand-mixing, etc

Comment: Sure. But how to reduce dependence on grid for electricity? In countries such as India, other energy needs for average family are lower than electrical needs. I hate coal based power

Comment: thanks, Dandavis! From my local conversation, I got to know that this may be a futile thought to pursue. saving about 0.3 Kcal is not good as directly expending it for physical work needs.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this has nothing to do with electrical design

Comment: This question reminds me of this video: https://youtu.be/S4O5voOCqAQ. TL;DW: unless you're doing it for fun, it's not realistic.

Comment: If you want to reduce your dependence on grid power - reduce your dependence on electricity. Easy as that. You won't be able to treadmill enough to get a litre of soup boiling or run your A/C. Your fridge maybe, the washing machine or dishwasher not. Bottomline: Find alternatives to the electrical devices instead of trying to run them without the grid electricity they're designed for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, to start with, an exercise treadmill does not produce power, it consumes power in order to provide a moving surface that you can run on.

However, a stationary bike or rowing machine can be fitted with a generator as a load. According to my rowing machine, I am putting out 200W for 30 minutes, for a total of about 100 W-h, burning about 500 kCal in the process.

Generators, batteries and inverters are not terribly efficient, so you'd be lucky to get half of that energy back to do useful things. Do the math!

Answer (score 4):

A human in good shape can easily put out 150W for a sustained period, say a couple of hours.  A highly trained athlete like a professional cyclist can put out peaks of >400W or even close to 1 hp for a short time.

So if you cycled to generate power at 150W sustained for say 2 hours, that's .3 kwh.  You could store that in a battery and run an inverter to power your devices.

With losses you might deliver 230 W-H and run a modern flat panel TV for 1-2 hours.  At the national average price of electricity of around $0.12 per kilowatt hour you would save $0.03 cents for the effort.

At your upper end of 1000 kcal you would generate 1162 WH and get back maybe 900 for a saving of maybe $0.10 on your bill.  If you do it every day you could save $3.00 a month or lots more if you live in a high energy cost state like CA.  You could watch maybe 3 hours of TV and run an LED bulb at the same time with that much energy.

The technology to do this exists and is relatively easy to implement, but humans are just not good generators of significant quantities of energy for the modern household.

Comment: Thanks for your lucid answer. I am not interested too much on $ savings but reducing my dependency and conservation. The pricing can change based on market and other political considerations. The payoff is more in terms of sense of gratification and independence I get

Comment: >>The technology to do this exists and is relatively easy to implement.. How to go about it? Can you give me a schematic? or any products available in the market?

Comment: It's beyond the scope of this forum to do a system design for you, but the basics are a treadmill or a cycle with the drivetrain hooked to a generator.  The generator drives a battery charge controller with maybe a knob to control the torque (resistance to the human powering the device.).  Then the batteries are hooked to an inverter to power AC connected devices, or used directly to power DC loads.

Comment: To take human power and put it into an inverter is really not that wise, there will be huge losses of power. Better to use a DC generator and DC lights, or other DC loads. Although I agree with the core of the message, it is not that much power anyway.

Comment: @ClaudioAviChami Of course, agreed, though the OP may not have a choice for certain loads.

Comment: In combination with solar and wind, human power could make a neat diversity resource for those windless nights! The most practical way is to buy/rescue an ex-gym step machine. Remove the car alternator that's in there as a cheap generator, they're very inefficient, and replace it with a BLDC motor or other suitable generator in the 500W to 1kW capacity range.

Comment: @sriram Bad news is that with this little amount of total energy produced, the solution to run on a threadmill or ride a modified bike will not be environmentally sound. The power that went into producing the copper, bearings, if applicable, magnets, of generators is a significant cost driver for these devices. So, chances are, if your system doesn't pay back its price by saving in your power bill, it's just spending the energy somewhere else. The feeling of independence and gratification would still work :)

Comment: @marcus: Yes. that too. it applies for today's many alt. energy production, though those are far better innovations by far. I was long pestered by this thought. Today I got some mud cleared . Thanks to everyone!

Comment: I've been thinking about the same thing. it would reduce weight-related health problems and reduce stress on electrical network. imagine a whole doing this.

Comment: @R.Joshi the bodily benefits aside, the load taken off the grid would be  absolutely totally extremely self-evidently negligible.